# To be obliged" Vs "To be obligated" in AmE

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning, word-difference

I was wondering if an AmE native speaker could let me know the semantic nuance between the two sentences caused by using similar verbs "obligate" and "oblige" in my self-made the examples below.

> - I’m obliged to do this.
> - I’m obligated to do this.

For me, they both mean the same thing, but perhaps they have some serious semantic differences.
P.s. I've already read [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4625/what-is-the-difference-between-to-oblige-and-to-obligate) thread, but I couldn't get much of it.

Comment: There is an answer here: [What is the difference between “to oblige” and “to obligate”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4625/what-is-the-difference-between-to-oblige-and-to-obligate)

Comment: I don't need to help you; I want to help you. I'm not obligated (by anyone), but I'm obliged (by my own will).

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang interesting answer. Thank you, though it is not completely clear yet. ;)

Comment: @Peter thank you, but please have another look on my question. ;)

Comment: "To be obligated" tends to have a legal meaning/binding where one **must** do *something* "Students are obligated to pay off their loans, or have a bad credit rating", "US expats are obligated to file annual tax returns no matter where in the world they are." "Obliged" may have more of a moral binding. In the US south, when *someone* does something nice for you, you could say "Thank you very much, much obliged." meaning "Thank you very much, I'm in your debt." I am obliged (morally) to repay your nice gesture, but I am not obligated to do so."

Answer (score 2):

"Obliged" implies a certain degree of *gratitude*, or some small measure of *indebtedness*  For example

> I am obliged to you for your help

implies that I appreciate your help, and I might return the favor at some point in time, but nothing more.  Meanwhile

> I am obligated to you for your help

*does* imply a debt that ought to be repaid.  As Peter points out, in some contexts an *obligation* includes legal and moral binding, whereas "obliged" is much more lax and relative to the individual.

[Apparently in the past "obliged" was much more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=obligated%2C+obliged&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), although examples of "obligated" from 200 years ago contain the same nuance as the word has today.